# Getting issues in a code that zips all files in a given directory

Tags: python

I am executing following code to zip all files in the given directory. If I open a zip file just to create it,the program keeps pounding data on the zip. The problem is with following statements:

```
with ZipFile("Python_archive.zip", 'w') as newZip:
    pass
```

If I put these two lines inside the `if root == BaseDir` condition the program works fine. I don't see a reason for the difference in outcome. Can anyone explain please?

The complete program:

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

BaseDir = r'F:\Study Notes\Python'
os.chdir(BaseDir)

with ZipFile("Python_archive.zip", 'w') as newZip:
    pass
for root, dir, file in os.walk(BaseDir):
    if root == BaseDir:
        for f in file:
            with ZipFile("Python_archive.zip", 'a') as newZip:
                newZip.write(f)
                print(f + " has been archived....")
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what wents wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For each directory in your BaseDir(including BaseDir), os.walk(BaseDir) yeilds the current director, list of directories and files(non directories).

For example: ('BaseDirPath', ['dir1', 'dir2'], ['file1', 'file2'])

```
with ZipFile("Python_archive.zip", 'a') as newZip:
      newZip.write(f)
      print(f + " has been archived....")
```

The above code zips all the files( Non directories) in your BaseDir if used with the condition `if root == BaseDir:`. When you have multiple directories and each directory contains some other files, the below code would error out

```
for root, dir, file in os.walk(BaseDir):
    for f in file:
```

file in the above code is a list of file names, look at the example above. You are trying to iterate over the list of file names(inside every directory) and zip them in your current folder but the file names are not found in the current folder and this shouldn't work.

This can be done easily using shutil.

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive('Python_archive', 'zip', BaseDir)
```